# Question about "tikzpicture"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a question regarding using "tikzpicture". I intend to draw a figure, which includes a top rectangular, middle circle and bottom rec. I tried and drew what I wanted with considering coordination for each shape. But I would like to consider the position of each shape depending on the position of the upper shape. I coded what I want but there is an intersection between my shaps.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{cir}=[circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3cm]
\tikzstyle{rec}=[rectangle,draw=black!50,fill=black!20,thick,
    inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3cm]
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[rec] (top_rec)                            {};
     \node[cir] (middle_cir) [below of=top_rec]      {};
     \node[rec] (down_rec)   [below of=middle_cir]   {};
     \end{tikzpicture}   
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here also is what I got [image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. And while you're at it, feel free to add a sketch of the desired result, since your question is not clear enough, to me at least.

Comment: Hi @SebGlav, Thanks, I made some changes to be more clear.

Comment: I suspect the problem is the node distance, which is too small.

Comment: But I think it should start to draw a circle from the bottom of the top rectangular not middle?

Comment: Note that [tikzstyle is deprecated and should be replaced by tikzset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles).

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want?

[image]

Observe that I changed the anchor in the node style and changed their positions making use of `at` and passing the anchor explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{cir}=[circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3cm,anchor=north] % added anchor
\tikzstyle{rec}=[rectangle,draw=black!50,fill=black!20,thick,
    inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3cm,anchor=north] % added anchor
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[]
     \node[rec] (top_rec)                            {A};
     \node[cir] (middle_cir) at (top_rec.south)      {B}; % changed
     \node[rec] (down_rec)   at (middle_cir.south)   {C}; % changed
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{Caption}
   \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks yes that's it. But if there is a small gap between shapes, that would be nicer. I'll try it.

Comment: Well, in this case it is better to adjust the node distance and your code should  work again.

Comment: Note that [tikzstyle is deprecated and should be replaced by tikzset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles).

Answer (score 5):

With use of the `chains` and `positioning` library, and defining nodes style as options of `tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt,
  start chain = going below,
     C/.style = {circle, draw=blue!50,thick, fill=blue!20,
                 inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3cm,
                 on chain},
     R/.style = {draw=black!50, thick, fill=black!20,
                 inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3cm,
                 on chain}
                        ]
\node[R] (n1)   {};
\node[C] (n2)   {};
\node[R] (n3)   {};
     \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result of compilation is:

[image]

**Addendum:**
Regarding your comment with your new request:

- Please don't add some code to my answer which change it. If you have new problem, please ask new question, if you like to clarify your problem, edit your question and describe it there, that it can be seen to other members of site.
- Arrows with labels between rectangles in your images you can draw as edges with quotes. See MWE below.
- In MWE below is changed nodes style declaration too. I do this to show one more possibilities how to define it and that they support your new request in comment.
- Style and text of quotes you can change according to your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt,
  start chain = going below,
  base/.style = {draw=#1!50, thick, fill=#1!20,
                 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=3cm,
                 on chain}, % <--- new 
     C/.style = {circle, base=blue},    % <--- changed
     R/.style = {base=black},           % <--- changed
       every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb, semithick, bend angle=45},    % <---  for edges
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, font=\small\bfseries}   % <--- for quotes on edges
                        ]
\node[R] (n1)   {};
\node[C] (n2)   {};
\node[R] (n3)   {};
% edges
\draw   (n1.west)  edge [bend right, "A"] (n3.west)
        (n3.east)  edge [bend right, "B"] (n1.east);
     \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for it. Just wondering how I can label the edges? If there are two edges one from top rectangular to bottom rectangular and one from bottom rectangular to top rectangular?

Comment: @AliAkbarSohrabiYousefkhan, I do not understand your commend. If you have new request, please edit your  question or better ask new question. Both answers solve what you ask.

Comment: Thanks now it solves my problem. Sure I just wanted to add new comments but I had a limited number of characters, then have to edit your code, sorry about it.

Comment: @AliAkbarSohrabiYousefkhan, since your problem is solved, seems that now is time to upvote and accept my answer :-).

Comment: sure. Thanks again  :)